# Unable to setprop - avc denied?

Tags: android, linux, firebase, samsung-mobile, selinux

I was trying to setup firebase debug mode for app on Samsung S7 and couldn't

> adb shell setprop firebase.analytics.debug-mode com.roostertech.net.app
>
> avc:  denied  { set } for property=firebase.analytics.debug-mode pid=19845 uid=2000 gid=2000 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_prop:s0 tclass=property_service permissive=0

Randomly tried to set other property and was denied as well

> avc:  denied  { set } for property=log.wtf pid=21107 uid=2000 gid=2000 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:log_prop:s0 tclass=property_service permissive=0
>
> avc:  denied  { set } for property=firebase pid=21086 uid=2000 gid=2000 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_prop:s0 tclass=property_service permissive=0

But this property log.tag.FA can be set just fine

> adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I couldn't find any documentation on what are the allowed properties that can be set?

Answer (score 1):

Every property can have its own context as you can see in the error messages.
Mappings of properties to SELinux contexts are defined in `property_contexts` files such as [system/sepolicy/private/property_contexts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/heads/pie-release/private/property_contexts).

You need to make sure that the context your process runs in (`shell`) is allowed to change a property of context `default_prop`.

You need to define the `allow` policy for that in one of your `.te` files.

```
set_prop(shell, default_prop)
```

If you want to find out which properties `shell` is currently allowed to set, you would ideally check the compiled selinux file in `$OUT/root/sepolicy`. Since I do not have a command at hand for how to do that I suggest you grep for rules instead and assume for now that all of them are compiled into the `sepolicy` file.

```sh
grep -rni "set_prop(shell" --include="*.te"
```